# Is it possible to hide chapter numbering for non-chapter headers and TOC listings

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I'm writing an edited collection of essays using a Scrivener-MMD-latex workflow (using the memoir class) and would like to hide chapter numbering for all items that aren't actually chapters. Here's a visual of what I'm trying to eliminate So, in the TOC I'd like to hide the numbering marked in red

[image: screenshot1]

Similarly, in the text, I'd like to omit numbering as marked:

[image]

I'm already using:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
```

to hide subsections and below from the TOC, but am wondering if there is a similarly simple way to do this within my header using the memoir class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably overwrite the \thesection command and replace it by something like

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

Comment: That was it - exact outcome I was hoping for. Thanks for this quick help!